# VB.net execute SQL Server ExecuteNonQuery crash

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

This is VB.net executes some SQL code:

```
Dim dc As New SqlCommand
Dim Strsql As String = ""
dc.Connection = cnn_myself

Strsql = "SET IDENTITY_INSERT gprs_route.dbo.landmark ON;
Insert into gprs_route.dbo.landmark ( Landmark_ID , Landmark_Name , Area_ID , Class_ID , Lon , Lan ) values (4189,'test1121',1,0,121432512,24967338);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT gprs_route.dbo.landmark OFF;"

dc.CommandText = Strsql
dc.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

it will crash at `dc.ExecuteNonQuery()` and the application will popup the error message dialog show below:

> System.InvalidCastException:
>   從字串 "資料表 'gprs_route.dbo.landmark' 不具" 至型別 'Boolean' 的轉換是無效的。
>   (Converting from string table 'gprs_route.dbo.landmark' to type Boolean is useless)
>   System.FormatException: 輸入字串格式不正確(the input string format is not correct)。
>   於 Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ParseDouble(String Value, NumberFormatInfo NumberFormat)
>   於 Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean(String Value)
>   --- 內部例外狀況堆疊追蹤的結尾(Inner exception stacktrace end) ---
>   於 Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean(String Value)
>   於 ITMIS.System_Setup.Btn_Yes_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   於 System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   於 Infragistics.Win.UltraControlBase.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   於 Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraButtonBase.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>   於 Infragistics.Win.Misc.UltraButton.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
>   於 System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>   於 System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>   於 System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
>   於 System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>   於 System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)

This is the table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[landmark]
(
     [Landmark_ID] int NOT NULL IDENTITY(3064,1) ,
     [Landmark_Name] nvarchar(150) NULL ,
     [Area_ID] int NULL ,
     [Class_ID] int NULL ,
     [Lon] int NULL ,
     [Lan] int NULL 
)
```

This is full function code below

```
Public Function Landmark_Insert(ByVal Data() As String) As String 

    Dim r As SqlDataReader
    Dim c As New SqlCommand("Select max(Landmark_ID) as Landmark_ID from gprs_route.dbo.landmark", cnn_myself)

    r = c.ExecuteReader

    r.Read()

    Data(0) = (Convert.ToInt32(r.Item("Landmark_ID").ToString) + 1).ToString()

    Dim dc As New SqlCommand
    Dim Strsql As String = ""

    Select Case Data.Length
        Case 4
            Strsql += "SET IDENTITY_INSERT gprs_route.dbo.landmark ON;"
            Strsql += "Insert into gprs_route.dbo.landmark ( "
            Strsql += "Landmark_ID , "
            Strsql += "Landmark_Name , "
            Strsql += "Area_ID , "
            Strsql += "Class_ID , "
            Strsql += "Lon , "
            Strsql += "Lan ) "
            Strsql += "values (" & Data(0) & ",'" & Data(1) & "'," & Data(2) & "," & Data(3) & "," & 121432512 & "," & 24967338 & ");"
            Strsql += "SET IDENTITY_INSERT gprs_route.dbo.landmark OFF;"

            MessageBox.Show(Strsql) 

            dc.Connection = cnn_myself
            dc.CommandText = Strsql

        Case 6
            'it won't call this....
    End Select
    Try
        MessageBox.Show("1")
        dc.ExecuteNonQuery() ' crash and show Exception error dialog
        MessageBox.Show("2")
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return ex.Message
    End Try
End Function
```

How to fix the crash problem?

Comment: Translating the non-english characters would be helpful.

Comment: Shouldn't `dc.CommandText = Strsql` come after the line where `Strsql` is assigned `SET IDENTITY_INSERT...`?

Comment: @Phylyp, good eye :)

Comment: @Phylyp,yes,you are right

Comment: @Phylyp, both the SET IDENTITY_INSERT statements are needed,or there is an error,because Landmark_ID column data type is 'int NOT NULL IDENTITY(3064,1)'

Comment: That said, I'm still puzzled at how an `InvalidCastException` and a `FormatException` are being thrown.

Comment: Could you please provide the complete code within this method: `ITMIS.System_Setup.Btn_Yes_Click()`. I believe there's a mistake in the code for that, since the very next call in the stack is to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Conversions.ToBoolean`, and things go downhill from there on.

Comment: You don't need to add the SET IDENTITY_INSERT.. to your sql query because Landmark_ID is already set as an IDENTITY column. Also, what happens if you set the dc.CommandType to CommandType.Text

Comment: Since there's no mention of *any* classes from the `SqlClient` namespace in that stack trace, I suspect you've misidentified the source of the error. As such, any speculation about the SQL code shown is pointless.

Comment: What is the relationship between the method `Btn_Yes_Click` seen in the stack trace and `Landmark_Insert` that you've provided above?

Comment: Btn_Yes_Click will call Landmark_Insert

Comment: Could you give the code for Btn_Yes_Click, the error appears to originate there.

Comment: @敬錞潘 - look at the stack trace again. `Btn_Yes_Click` is in there, `Landmark_Insert` isn't, and it appears to be complex enough that it won't be inlined. You need to *accurately* locate the actual source of the error rather than flinging unrelated code at us.

Comment: I am sure that dc.ExecuteNonQuery() crash,because I add MessageDialog at before and after executing dc.ExecuteNonQuery(),it won't show dialog after calling dc.ExecuteNonQuery()

Comment: @敬錞潘 - the stack trace disagrees with your statement, as it does not list a call to `Landmark_Insert`. Go ahead, look and the stack trace and see if `Landmark_Insert` is listed there. Its not, which implies the crash occurred outside `Landmark_Insert`. Is there any reason you're reluctant to share `Btn_Yes_Click` code, Damien and I've requested it thrice.

Comment: @Phylyp - I don't know why the stack trace doesn't show Landmark_Insert,but I am sure that these code will show MessageBox.Show("1"),then crash and show stacktrace error dialog

Comment: @敬錞潘 - Exceptions thrown by ExecuteNonQuery are being swallowed by the surrounding `Catch` block and the message of the exception is being returned back to `Btn_Yes_Click`. What it does with that message, we've no idea - but to find out (and get the *actual* error that is happening and a correct stack trace), please *remove* that pointless `Try`/`Catch` block.

Answer (score 0):

If I take away try catch and SET IDENTITY_INSERT gprs_route.dbo.landmark ON/Off.

It's working successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You should use sqlcommand with type Commandtype text and with Sqlparameters for sending data in insert query by setting correct dbtype
You can refer below article
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2017/07/01/parameterized-queries.aspx